# Run code when VB.NET application starts

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

How do i make code run when an application starts up?

I want to open up a config file and parse it and then set up the user where they left off last. I built the methods for reading the config file but I dont know how to make those methods run automatically when the program starts up.  Is there some Start() method that i need to look for?  In an android app for instance there are Create() Start() and Resume() methods that I can use to call code when the app starts.

Comment: What sort of app is this? Windows Store? WPF? Silverlight? Winforms? Console? ASP.Net?

Comment: Winform from what I can tell. I am editing someone elses code. is there a way for me to tell?  I'm obviously no expert at .net

Comment: If you go to your My Project page, there should be an Application Events button at the bottom of the General tab (unless thing have changed significantly since I last used Visual Studio). Try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your application is running in a Console, then simply put your code inside the Main method.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    ' Say hi in VB.NET.
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world")
    End Sub
End Module
```

If your code is running in a WinForm then put it on `Form_Load` event. Note: Replace `Form1` with the name of your Form.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

If your code is WPF then subscribe to the Loaded event:

```
public MyWindow()
{
  Loaded += MyWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // do work here
}
```

Comment: So I put my code inside of the form_load() method as described in option 2. is this overloading the old form_load method? This function doesn't seem to be called when the application loads.  I feel like I'm still not understanding somthing

Comment: I got it working. I needed to make the method as you described (The naming convention is just for good practice it seems?).  I finally found the load event in VS IDE.  Thanks for your help